# if then else twice and if not found then run a command

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
if [[ $(find /path/to/folder1 -type f -not -path "*configs*" -size -800k 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
    echo "[[Warning]]: The files size is under 800 Kilobytes"

    if [[ $(find /path/to/another/folder -type f \( ! -iname "123.file*" \) -not -path "*logs*" -size -40k 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
        echo "[[Warning]]: The file size is under 40 Kilobytes"
    fi
else

   Run a command here

fi
```

The target is:

Get an echo if a file under size found in any of the above paths or get both echo if a file under size found on both paths and run the command at the end only if not files under size found at any of the above two paths.

Both checks are tested and working but it seems that I have the `if` or `else` statements in wrong order?

Comment: using cmd-substitution with `$( find ...)` seems unhelpful here, as you're not comparing any output to a string (or other logic test). Such code can be simplified with `if find ... 2>/dev/null ; then echo stuff ; if find ... 2>/dev/null; then echo more ; else cmd ; fi`. Redirecting errors before you have a working solution is usually conterproductive, so drop the `2>/dev/null`s for now? Good luck.

Comment: Also, your messages, `echo "[[Warning]]: The file size ...` would be more helpful for debugging your issue if they included the names of the found files. But your current code doesn't really support that. So, at least for debugging, I would add `-ls` option to `find` cmds, so you can confirm your logic is working as you require. Good luck.

Comment: @ shellter  Checking what you recommend me i am getting always for both checks that a file with small size always exist but that's not the case :(

if find /path/to/folder -type f -not -path "*configs*" -size -800k
then 
    echo "[[Warning]]: The file at /path/to/folder is under 800 Kilobytes"  
if find /path/to/folder2 -type f \( ! -iname "123.file*" \) -not -path "*logs*" -size -40k
then 
    echo "[[Warning]]: The file at /path/to/folder2 is under under 40 Kilobytes"
else 
echo run command
fi
fi

Comment: @shellter : I think the idea of the command substitiution is to test whether `find` produced **any** output. It would have been clearar to write `if [[ -n $(find...) ]]`, but if no operator is present, `if` just checks for the presence of a string. So the `if` is not wrong IMO.

Comment: @user1934428 : Thanks for pointing that out. and yes, I agree `-n` would help make that approach more self-documenting. But my real objection is that the code is not set up in a way to help the OP debug the problem. And I really can't make out what is happening in the OPs comment above. Maybe OP can update Q with output of individual find commands using the `-ls` option? Well.... good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

That should work what you have. An easier way would be to use OR (||) in structure below. If both of those statements are false, then you run command.

```
if statementA || statementB then...

else ...
```

Comment: On my example the second check doesn't work....But if i test them separate both work. The problem is that i can't combine them....

Comment: I ran the general logic as 
```
if true; then
    echo "[[Warning]]: The files size is under 800 Kilobytes"

    if true; then
        echo "[[Warning]]: The file size is under 40 Kilobytes"
    fi
else

   Run a command here

fi
```
and got both to output. I didn't check the exact commands, but if either don't run, it must be something with syntax.

Comment: I did the general case https://repl.it/@EliaAhadi/ifelse-test

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` is already executed when the first `if` gets false. You could do a

```
if [[ $(find ....) ]] || [[ $(find ....) ]]; then
else
  run
fi
```

or

```
if [[ -n $(find ....) || -n $(find ....) ]]; then
else
  run
fi
```

but this would only take care about the running command; you want, however, also display an individual message if the find commands succeed.

There are several possibilities. The easiest would be IMO to use a control variable:

```
run_command=1
if [[ $(find ....) ]]; then
   echo ....
   run_command=0
fi
if [[ $(find ....) ]]; then
   echo ....
   run_command=0
fi
if ((run_command == 1)); then
   run ...
fi
```